# Under 600px css issue

Tags: html, css, mobile, drop-down-menu

so, the problem I'm having is really tough to explain, but, I am trying to make my navigation act differently for when the page is less than 600px in width. I've got it almost working the way I want, but when I click the menu button when it gets under 600px, it creates a dropdown over top of the content below it, where I want it to move the content to the bottom of the menu when it's expanded. of course, when the site is full width, I still want the menu to go overtop of the content.

css

```
.main-navigation {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 150px;
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #2CB3B4;
    height: 44px;
}

.main-navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.main-navigation li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.main-navigation li a:after {
    content: '';
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    border-top: 4px solid white;
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 4px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.main-navigation li a:only-child:after {
    content: '';
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.main-navigation a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.82em 1em;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.main-navigation ul ul {
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
    background: #2F2F2F;
    z-index: 99999;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
}

.main-navigation ul ul ul {
    left: -999em;
    top: 0;
}

.main-navigation ul ul a {
}

.main-navigation ul ul li {
    width: 100%;
}

.main-navigation li:hover > a,
.main-navigation li.focus > a {
    color: #FFF;
    background: #2F2F2F;
}

.main-navigation ul ul :hover > a,
.main-navigation ul ul .focus > a {
}

.main-navigation ul ul a:hover,
.main-navigation ul ul a.focus {
        background: #000;
}

.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul,
.main-navigation ul li.focus > ul {
    left: auto;
}

.main-navigation ul ul li:hover > ul,
.main-navigation ul ul li.focus > ul {
    left: 100%;
}

.main-navigation .current_page_item > a,
.main-navigation .current-menu-item > a,
.main-navigation .current_page_item > a:hover,
.main-navigation .current-menu-item > a:hover {
    background: #4D4D4D;
}

.main-navigation .current_page_ancestor > a {
    background: #4D4D4D;
}

.main-navigation ul ul .curremt_page_parent {
    color: green;
    background: #313131;
}

/* Small menu. */
.menu-toggle,
.main-navigation.toggled ul {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .menu-toggle {
        display: block;
        height: 44px;
        padding: 0 1em;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-decoration: none;
        line-height: 1.5em;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        background: #2cb3b4;
        border: 0;
        box-shadow: none;
    }

    .main-navigation.toggled .nav-menu {
        display: block;
        border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
        padding-left: 0;
        position: relative;
        min-width: 100%;
    }

    .main-navigation.toggled {
        min-width: 100%;
    }

    .main-navigation.toggled a {
        display: block;
        background: #2cb3b4;
        min-width: 100%;
    }

    .main-navigation.toggled ul {
        display: block;
        border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    }

    .main-navigation ul {
        display: none;
        padding-left: 0;
        float: none;
    }

}
```

html

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false">Primary Menu</button>
            <div class="menu-guides-container"><ul id="primary-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-114" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-114"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/achievement-guides/">Achievement Guides</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-105" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-105"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-11/">Guides 11</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-106" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-106"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-10/">Guides 10</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-107" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-107"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-8/">Guides 9</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-108" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-108"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-7/">Guides 7</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-115" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-115"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/map-completion-guides/">Map Completion Guides</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-101" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-101"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-15/">Guides 15</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-102" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-102"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-14/">Guides 14</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-103" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-103"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-13/">Guides 13</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-104" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-104"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-12/">Guides 12</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-109" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-109"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-6/">Guides 6</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-110" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-110"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-5/">Guides 5</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-111" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-111"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-4/">Guides 4</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-112" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-112"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-3/">Guides 3</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-123" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-123"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-16/">A Really Long Header Width</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-113" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-113"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-2/">Guides 2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-122" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-122"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-16/">A Really Long Header Width</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-121" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-121"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/guides-16-2/">Guides 16</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div></nav>
```

Comment: Please make a Fiddle or other demo with a working example of your issue.

Comment: I cant seem to get the fiddle to function properly with the <600px part of the code. but here: http://jsfiddle.net/g7nncn2m/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your floats, absolute positioning and negative left margins that are cascading down into your small screen media query.
I recommend starting your nav styles with your basic small screen rules then use `@media screen and (min-width: 600px)` to declare your large screen drop down menu styles. This way you you don't have to reset all of those floats, positionings, margins etc. that are causing your small screen problems. Your css will be more efficient that way.